# async void ASP.NET . Как использовать асинхронные операции при разработке под WEB?

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, asp.net, asp.net-webforms

Возникла необходимость написания парсера в вебе.
И стокнулся я с проблемой великой: веб `asp.net`  ругается при вызове функций, использующих `async void`, и как следствие работать оно не хочет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Форма

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using WebApplication1.Parser.Core;
using WebApplication1.Parser.Core.habra;

namespace WebApplication1.Parser
{
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    //Создадим поле ParserWorker
    ParserWorker<string[]> parser;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        parser = new ParserWorker<string[]>(
                    new HabraParser()
                );
        
        parser.OnComleted += Parser_OnComleted;
        parser.OnNewData += Parser_OnNewData;
    }

    private void Parser_OnNewData(object arg1, string[] arg2)
    {
        foreach(var a in arg2)
            ListTitles.Items.Add(a);
    }

    private void Parser_OnComleted(object obj)
    {
        ListTitles.Items.Add("");
    }

    protected void btn_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        parser.Settings = new HabraSetings(1,2);
        parser.Start();
    }

    protected void btn_End_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        parser.Abort();
    }
}
}
```

ParserWorker

```
using AngleSharp.Html.Parser;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication1.Parser.Core
{
//Обобщенный класс
class ParserWorker<T> where T:class
{
    //Добавим классу поле с обощенным типом IParser
    IParser<T> parser;
    //Добавим поле типа где будут хранится настройки для парсера
    IParserSetings parserSetings;
    //Поле
    HtmlLoader loader;

    //Переменная для контроля парсинга
    bool isActive;

    //Добавим пару публичных полей, разделим их регионом
    #region Properlies 
    //Свойство поля
    public IParser<T> Parser
    {
        get
        {
            return parser;
        }
        set
        {
            parser = value;
        }
    }
    public IParserSetings Settings
    {
        get
        {
            return parserSetings;
        }
        set
        {
            parserSetings = value;
            //Создаем экземпляр с новыми натсройками парсера
            loader = new HtmlLoader(value);
        }
    }

    //Делаем переменную isActive доступной только для чтения
    public bool IsActive
    {
        get
        {
            return isActive;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    //СОбытие, возвращающее спарсенные данные
    //передаем ссылку на парсер и сами данные
    public event Action<object, T> OnNewData;
    //Событие отвечает за информирование при завершении работы парсера
    public event Action<Object> OnComleted;


    //Констрпуктор, где принимаются экземпляры, реализуюшие интерфейс IParser
    public ParserWorker(IParser<T> parser)
    {
        //Присваиваем значение аргумента полю
        this.parser = parser;
    }

    //Второй конструктор, который помимо парсера
    //ПРинимает настройки парсера
    //Чтобы не дублировать код передадим парсер из первого конструктора
    public ParserWorker(IParser<T> parser, IParserSetings parserSetings) : this(parser)
    {
        //Настройки парсера запишем в поле
        this.parserSetings = parserSetings;
    }

    //Методы запуска и остановки парсера
    public void Start()
    {
        isActive = true;
        //Делаем через Task чтобы все работало асинхронно
        //Task.Run(() => Worker());
        Worker();
    }
    public void Abort()
    {
        isActive = false;
    }

    //Закрытый асинхронный метод, контралирующипй процее парсинга
    private async void Worker()
    {
        for(int i = parserSetings.StartPoint; i< parserSetings.EndPoint;i++)
        {
            if(!isActive)
            {
                OnComleted?.Invoke(this);
                return;
            }

            //Получаем исходный код страницы с индексом из цикла
            var source = await loader.GetSourceByPageId(i);
            //Создаем html парсер, доступный из AngleCharp
            var domParser = new HtmlParser();

            //Спарсим асинхронно исходный код и получим документ, с которым можем работать.
            var document = domParser.ParseDocumentAsync(source);

            //Передаем нашему парсеру спарсенные данные
            var result = parser.Parse(document);

            //Передает ссылку и результат
            OnNewData?.Invoke(this, (T)result);
        }

        //Вызывает событие, если парсер сам законнчил работу
        OnComleted?.Invoke(this);
        isActive = false;

    }

}
}
```

HtmlLoader

```
  using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication1.Parser.Core
{
    class HtmlLoader
    {
    readonly HttpClient client;
    readonly string url;

    //Открытый конструктор класса 
    public HtmlLoader(IParserSetings setings)
    {
        //Инициализация поля клиент
        client = new HttpClient();
        //Инициализируем url и построим ссылку для запроса из свойств
        url = $"{setings.BaseURL}/{setings.Prefix}/";
    }

    public async Task<string> GetSourceByPageId(int id)
    {
        var currentUrl = url.Replace("{CurentId}", id.ToString());
        //Принимает ерзультат метода GetAsync по указаной ссылке
        var response = await client.GetAsync(currentUrl);
        //Переменная где будет храниться исходный код страницы
        string source = null;

        //Проверка на null & статус должен быть ОК
        if(response != null && response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            source = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        return source;
    }
}
}
```

И как заставить это работать в вебе идей уже нет.
Пробовал через `asyns Task` но просто не происходит ровным счетом ничего.

Comment: В ошибке ясно сказано: "метод должен вернуть задачу и объект должен ожидать". Вместо `void` используйте `Task`. И добавьте `await` в месте вызова.

Comment: Антипаттерн async void: https://habr.com/en/company/otus/blog/488082/

Comment: Удалось разобраться? Был ли полезен отет? Если да, отметьте его принятым.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно ожидать завершения асинхронного метода

```cs
protected async void btn_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    parser.Settings = new HabraSetings(1,2);
    await parser.Start();
}
```

```cs
public Task Start()
{
    isActive = true;
    return Worker();
}

private async Task Worker()
{
    // ...
}
```

И немного подправлю вам сетевой метод не меняя его поведения.

```cs
public async Task<string> GetSourceByPageId(int id)
{
    var currentUrl = url.Replace("{CurentId}", id.ToString());
    using (var response = await client.GetAsync(currentUrl, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
    {
        return response.IsSuccessStatusCode ? await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() : null;
    }
}
```